# Why UIView has not got a transform.a and transform.d?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I put a `UIScrollView` fill in the main view,and put a `UIView` named `_contentView` in it,finally put some `UIView` named `_annotationView` to the `_contentView.It` might be described like below:

```
_scrollView
           - |
           -  _contentView
                   *|
                    *_annotationView1
                    *_annotationView2
                    *……
```

When I implemented the `UISrollView` event "`scrollViewDidZoom`",and I got `_contentView.transform.a` and `_contentView.transform.d` `data.However`,the subviews of _contentView like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"content scale:%f", _contentView.transform.a);  //changed every time
    NSLog(@"content scale:%f", _contentView.transform.d);  //changed every time
    for (UIView *view in [_contentView subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"x:%f",view.transform.a);   //always got 1
        NSLog(@"y:%f",view.transform.d);   //always got 1
    }
}
```

Why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

A subview transformation matrix is relative to its superview.

In other words, if you just apply an affine transform matrix to  `_contentView`, its subviews will still have an identity matrix which is composed to that of the superview. This is reflected in this paragraph from [Apple's View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html):

> The coordinate system of each subview builds upon the coordinate systems of its ancestors. So when you modify a view’s transform property, that change affects the view and all of its subviews. However, these changes affect only the final rendering of the views on the screen. Because each view draws its content and lays out its subviews relative to its own bounds, it can ignore its superview’s transform during drawing and layout.

Also take a look at "Figure 1-6  Rotating a view and its content" in the same linked document.

Comment: Thanks.Well,how to fix the size of subviews while _contentView is zooming in or out?Like the annotations of system map app,they get a fixed size.

Comment: you can scale the subview while scrolling so that it is made larger when zooming out, and smaller when zooming in.

Comment: yeah,I also do that.But I find the zoom rate may be not the same.The subview of _contentView zoom in smaller than its default's.I just do like this:if (_contentView.transform.a > 1 && _contentView.transform.a <= 1.5) {
                CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2-_contentView.transform.a, 2-_contentView.transform.d);
                view.transform = transform;
            }